# Azure Active Directory B2C - IE Issues

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We're using Azure Active Directory B2C with custom policies, but sporadically, we're seeing the below issue in IE.

[image]

I can't find any documentation on what this might, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks like it is saying that the client id was not included in the request. Did you check the URL that it contains it when this error happens?

Comment: Hey @juunas, I'm just looking now and yes, the client_id is present in the URL when the error appears